# Not selecting item in combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox, lookup

I need the following behavior for WPF Combobox:
i need autofilter in combobox. Took the implementation from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/cec1b222-2849-4a54-bcf2-03041efcf304/). But when there are several items in dropdown that are almost same-when i press DOWN it just selects the first one from list and hides others(see video of current behavior here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WYAgMTxc4M). If i want the second possible-i have to select it with mouse or write down the whole item display name in editable part of combobox. Is it possible to select item without changing editable part of the combobox, until i press ENTER, for example?

Comment: Your video is marked private.

Comment: @CodeWarrior oops, forgot to change settings, thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is when you select the item, it fill the text area of **ComboBox**, than it notify that filter text changed and it applied new filter for the list, and the only one item remains in the list.

You should to rewrite this behavior that will apply filter only if **KeyPressed** / **KeyDown** / **KeyUp** events was fired.